# Encontrar palavras entre os caratecteres { }, e retirar do texto em PHP?

Tags: php, string

```
$comoesta = "{A,O} {portador,portadora} é o mais {especializada,especializado} para o serviço .";
```

Se for masculino:

```
$comodeveficar = "O portador é o mais especializado para o serviço  ";
```

Se for feminino:

```
$comodeveficar = "A portadora é o mais especializada para o serviço  ";
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pra fazer isso, você precisa seguir um padrão, ou a primeira é masculina ou é feminina, e a segunda é oposta a primeira:

```
$comoesta = "{O,A} {portador,portadora} é {o,a} mais {especializado,especializada} para o serviço .";

$resultadoMasculino = preg_replace("/\{([^\,]*)\,([^\}]*)\}/", "$1", $comoesta);

$resultadoFeminino = preg_replace("/\{([^\,]*)\,([^\}]*)\}/", "$2", $comoesta);
```

O que eu uso é a função preg_replace para diferenciar o masculino do feminino, sendo `$1` masculino, pois o primeiro valor antes da virgula é masculino, e `$2` feminino.

Você pode ler mais sobre expressões regulares [aqui](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_regular_expression.htm).

Aliás, excelente pergunta!!

Comment: muito obrigado, funcionou!

Comment: cool! +1 eventualmente `preg_replace("/\{(.*?),(.*?)\}/", "$1", $a);`

Answer (score 5):

Um exemplo bem simples usando `str_replace`.

Código:

```
<?php

// 1 = Masculino, 2 = Feminino.
$codGenero = 1;

$comoesta = "{A,O} {portador,portadora} é {o,a} mais {especializada,especializado} para o serviço .";

if($codGenero == 1) {
    $comoesta = str_replace("{A,O}", "O", $comoesta);
    $comoesta = str_replace("{o,a}", "o", $comoesta);
    $comoesta = str_replace("{portador,portadora}", "portador", $comoesta);
    $comoesta = str_replace("{especializada,especializado}", "especializado", $comoesta);
}
else {
    $comoesta = str_replace("{A,O}", "A", $comoesta);
    $comoesta = str_replace("{o,a}", "a", $comoesta);
    $comoesta = str_replace("{portador,portadora}", "portadora", $comoesta);
    $comoesta = str_replace("{especializada,especializado}", "especializada", $comoesta);
}

echo $comoesta;

?>
```

Saída se `$codGenero = 1`:

`O portador é o mais especializado para o serviço .`

Saída se `$codGenero = 2`:

`A portadora é a mais especializada para o serviço .`

Fonte: eu mesmo.

Comment: O problema é que as palavras eu não saberei quais vão vir.

Comment: Ah sim, desculpe, achei que fossem palavras fixas. Nesse caso é melhor usar o `preg_replace` mesmo, como o JuniorNunes disse. Ótima pergunta !